# Why import specific sub-packages in Python when the entire package has already been imported?

Tags: python

I am not a Python programmer, but I read a lot of Python scripts that import sub-packages from whole packages already imported.

For example:

```
  import multiprocessing
  from multiprocessing import Process
```

What exactly is the purpose of importing Process specifically when its entire parent package, multiprocessing, has already been imported?

Comment: I don't know why they did it, but for my own purposes I would do it for ease of usage of the sub-object, and to namespace others I'd use the parent if I wanted to use the name of that specific object for something else.

Comment: Importing a package will run that package's __init__.py file but not those contained in subpackages. If the subpackage needs that initialization in order to be used, you need to import the subpackage explicitly.

Comment: Note that `Process` is a class, not a sub-package.

Comment: @chepner Noted. It isn't a package I've used. There is a separation between the question and example. Pygame subpackages might be a better example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes the namespace/module accessible.

Then you can write :

```
p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Otherwise, if you had not used the line `from multiprocessing import Process`, you would have written:

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

---

The above code works, given you have defined the function f:

```
def f(name):
    print 'hello', name
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2nd case multiprocessing.Process is aliased to Process

Answer (score 1):

The first line, `import multiprocessing`, initializes the package and imports the name into the local namespace. This allows access to `multiprocess.Process`, `multiprocess.Pipe`, `multiprocess.Queue`, etc.

The second line, `from multiprocessing import Process`, simply imports the name `multiprocess.Process` directly into the current namespace, so that it can be referred to as `Process` rather than the longer `multiprocess.Process`. It could be replaced with

```
Process = multiprocessing.Process
```

since it only creates a new name for `multprocessing.Process`.

Python doesn't have a syntax for importing both an entire package/module's name *and* one or more names from that package/module with a single `import` statement.